# track downloads from server on ubuntu?

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu-10.04

Kinda server noob.  Is there a simple command to run on server access logs to track downloads of a particular file?  Running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

`$ grep "/path/to/file" /var/log/httpd/access.log | wc -l`

That looks for entries in your access log for '/path/to/file' and gives you a count of those lines.  Run it against more logs for more days.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill Weiss suggested, though older files are compressed, run `zgrep` on them. You can also use `tail` to see requested files in real time:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/access.log | grep "/path/to/file"
```

or to monitor multiple files:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/access.log | grep -E "(/path/to/file|/path/to/other/file)"
```